# How to query Wikidata in JavaScript using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparql, wikidata

I'd like to query Wikidata in JavaScript using the following three libraries: `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`, `encode.js`, `jquery.sparql.js`. The approach is similar to this one used here: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/3069/how-to-use-sparql-with-js-components

The error is in the line "`.filter("lang(?partOf) = 'en'")`". If I delete the filter line I get the results for `partOf` in all languages (that is the rest of the code works). If I add the filter line I get an empty array instead of only the result in English.

How should the `filter` command be adjusted?

```
<p id="demoWikidata"></p>

<script>
    $(function () {
         $.sparql("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
         .prefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
         .prefix("wdt", "http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/")
         .prefix("wd", "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/")
         .select(["?partOf"])
            .where("wd:Q151005", "wdt:P361", "?helpPartOf")
            .where("?helpPartOf", "rdfs:label", "?partOf")
            //.filter("lang(?partOf) = 'en'")
            .execute(cbfunction)

            function cbfunction(result) {
              document.getElementById("demoWikidata").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
            }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: everything works as expected with the FILTER. The generated query will be `SELECT ?partOf WHERE { wd:Q151005 wdt:P361 ?helpPartOf. ?helpPartOf rdfs:label ?partOf. FILTER ( lang(?partOf) = 'en' ) }`, you can check console to see the generated URL

Comment: That's the JSON result returned by the service: `/**/jQuery110205362868522281741_1546438908671({"query":{"count":1,"created":"2019-01-02T14:23:04Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"sparql":{"query":"PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> SELECT ?partOf WHERE { wd:Q151005 wdt:P361 ?helpPartOf. ?helpPartOf rdfs:label ?partOf. FILTER ( lang(?partOf) = 'en' ) }","result":{"partOf":{"type":"literal","value":"German Campaign of 1813"}}}}}});` - so it's for sure not empty